# Uploading an avatar to my profile in grails error

Tags: grails, avatar

I am new to grails and developing a web application such that a user updates profile details along with an avatar. I have a user controller that contains the logic to upload and save the avatar image. Unfortunately after choosing the avatar then upload, I get the this error which has troubled me for days:

```
No signature of method: eafya.User.current() is applicable for argument types: (grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsHttpSession) values: [Session Content: org.grails.FLASH_SCOPE = org.grails.web.servlet.GrailsFlashScope@d7b602 loggedOnUser = eafya.Patient : 1 messages = [] loginAudit = eafya.LoginAudit : 19 ] Possible solutions: count(), create(), ident(), collect(), insert(), collect(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

here is the controller:

```
package eafya

class UserController {
    def current(){}
    def select_avatar(){

    }
    def upload_avatar() {
        def user = User.current(session)  // or however you select the current user
        // Get the avatar file from the multi-part request
        def f = request.getFile('avatar')

        // List of OK mime-types
        def okcontents = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif']
        if (! okcontents.contains(f.getContentType())) {
            flash.message = "Avatar must be one of: ${okcontents}"
            render(view:'select_avatar', model:[user:user])
            return;
        }

        // Save the image and mime type
        user.avatar = f.getBytes()
        user.avatarType = f.getContentType()
        log.info("File uploaded: " + user.avatarType)

        // Validation works, will check if the image is too big
        if (!user.save()) {
            render(view:'select_avatar', model:[user:user])
            return;
        }
        flash.message = "Avatar (${user.avatarType}, ${user.avatar.size()} bytes) uploaded."
        redirect(action:'show')
    }
    def avatar_image() {
        def avatarUser = User.get(params.id)
        if (!avatarUser || !avatarUser.avatar || !avatarUser.avatarType) {
            response.sendError(404)
            return;
        }
        response.setContentType(avatarUser.avatarType)
        response.setContentLength(avatarUser.avatar.size())
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(avatarUser.avatar);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have an exception, that clearly states that your `User` class doesn't have a static `current( session )` method. What do you want from us?

Comment: @injecteer if its a session, I have created one. kindly if there's something missing that i need to add give me direction.am new with grails.